# Error: no instance of constructor "Camera::Camera" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I'm very new to programming but trying to learn!
I'm trying to update the Camera so I can start 3D Objects and other things in my Project.
So I needed to create 2 Structures, one for the Vector3 one for the Camera.

Vector3 – Has three floats called x, y and z.

Camera – Has three Vector3s called eye, center and up.

I need to define these structs in my HelloGL.h file and define my Vector3 first.
Then I defined my Camera pointer in the HelloGL header
But when I try to initialize  this in my HelloGL constructor I get the error

"Error: no instance of constructor "Camera::Camera" matches the argument list"

Here is the code which I think isn't working (The HelloGL.h and the HelloGL.cpp)

(HelloGL.h)

```
#pragma once

#define REFRESHRATE 16
#define Vector3 Vector3

#include <Windows.h> //Required for OpenGL on Windows
#include <gl/GL.h> //OpenGL
#include <gl/GLU.h> //OpenGL Utilities
#include "GL\freeglut.h" //freeglut library

class HelloGL
{
public:

HelloGL(int argc, char* argv[]);
~HelloGL();

void Display();

void Update();

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

Camera* camera;

private:

float rotation;
float rotationRect;
float rotationSquare;
float rotationTriangle;
};

class Vector3
{
public:

Vector3(float x, float y, float z);

private:

float x;
float y;
float z;

};

class Camera
{
public:

Camera(Vector3 eye, Vector3 center, Vector3 up);

private:

Vector3 eye;
Vector3 center;
Vector3 up;
};
```

(HelloGL.cpp)

```
#include "HelloGL.h"
#include "GLUTCallbacks.h"

HelloGL::HelloGL(int argc, char* argv[])
{

camera = new Camera();
rotation = 0.0f;
rotationRect = 0.0f;
rotationSquare = 0.0f;
rotationTriangle = 0.0f;
GLUTCallbacks::Init(this);
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(1, 1);
glutCreateWindow("Simple But Lit OpenGL Program");
glutDisplayFunc(GLUTCallbacks::Display);
glutTimerFunc(REFRESHRATE, GLUTCallbacks::Timer, REFRESHRATE);
glutKeyboardFunc(GLUTCallbacks::Keyboard);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 800);
gluPerspective(45, 1, 0.1, 1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glutMainLoop();

}

HelloGL::~HelloGL()
{

}
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

You only have defined a Camera with following constructor:

```
Camera(Vector3 eye, Vector3 center, Vector3 up);
```

while you are calling it with `camera = new Camera();`, the default constructor. Either you should add a constructor without parameters or pass the correct arguments to this constructor.

Comment: So If I wanted to pass it with the correct arguments, would I say:

camera = new Camera(eye, center, up);

Comment: `new Camera(Vector3{}, Vector3{}, Vector3{})` ? Or something similar, how do you pass arguments to any other function?

Comment: That passes the arguments, but however it still is giving the same error to each of the {}s.

Do you think that
    (Vector3 eye;
    Vector3 center;
    Vector3 up;)

Doesn't actually declare each of these and that's causing it to try and send something which doesn't exist?

PS: like I said, I am very new to programming so If it looks like I don't understand what you're trying to say or if I am missing a very basic thing please tell me, I'm trying to learn by myself and it's harder to realize my mistakes

Comment: You are new to programming and directly start with OpenGL? I would first recommend trying to write some command line utilities.
The {} is just a way to write the default constructor, you can read more about this syntax at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/133690

Comment: I know some java from learning it this year but little in C++, but thanks for the information I will look into that hopefully it can help me!